# Disabled editing of inline text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field which is inline editable. I use jQuery for that;

```
$el.on("click", ".editableTxt", function () {
    var currElmModelId = $(this).attr('data-model-id');
    var currElmModelAttr = $(this).attr('data-model-attr');
    var input = $('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': currElmModelAttr,
        'data-model-id': currElmModelId,
        'data-model-attr': currElmModelAttr,
        'class': 'editBox',
        'style': 'width:60px',
        'value': $(this).html()
    });
    $(this).parent().append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    input.focus();
});
```

My question is I need to add a privilige check to this...so there are 2 possibilities (View and Update)

So if user has only view priv, he'll just get to see static text and nothing should happen if he clicks on the text.
But if the user has Update priv, he'll get to see the static text and on click, the above jquery function should fire and he should be able to edit using inline text.

What is the best way to incorporate the same with the above code?

Answer (score 1):

depends on how the privilege is being checked and a simple if block can be used to handle that

```
var editPermissions = true; //false depending on the permission
$("#html").on("click", ".editableTxt", function () {
if (editPermissions) {
    var currElmModelId = $(this).attr('data-model-id');
    var currElmModelAttr = $(this).attr('data-model-attr');
    var input = $('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
            'name': currElmModelAttr,
            'data-model-id': currElmModelId,
            'data-model-attr': currElmModelAttr,
            'class': 'editBox',
            'style': 'width:60px',
            'value': $(this).html()
    });
    $(this).parent().append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    input.focus();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your anonymous function needs some way of knowing whether it should return without editing.

One way would be to set the `disabled` attribute on the `<input>` when you are generating it if the user doesn't have the privilege.

The javascript function could then have:

```
if ($(this).attr('disabled'))
    return;
```

Just be sure to check privilges on the server side when the data comes in since a malicious user could alter the field on the browser side regardless of your efforts.